Unknown South African independent horror film
I'm looking for a movie for my wife that I can't seem to remember the name. It's an independent horror film from South Africa. The people speak with accents that sound Australian to me, but I suppose that's just the way people sound in South Africa. 
It is set in an abandoned hospital or something similar, where the government is performing experiments on the people there. I want to say that these experiments turn people into zombie-like creatures, but the movie IS NOT about zombies.
In the end of the movie, a few of the people get to the roof of the facility and they're shot by security forces (snipers) surrounding the building... nobody survives.
I know it's from South Africa because I watched the commentary track. The director kept saying his budget was extremely limited, and they used a real abandoned hospital during filming. The movie was actually quite popular but I'm unable to find it using this search criteria.
Any help would be appreciated.

Sounds like Rancid (AKA Expiration) from 2011.

Four applicants, with their own hidden agendas, are accepted by a mysterious corporation to participate in a medical experiment at an isolated testing facility. With no instructions and no supplies, the human lab rats must fend for themselves and figure out what part of the experiment each one is playing. 

The survivors are indeed gunned down by snipers near the end. The film was shot on a small budget in an abandoned hospital in South Africa. Here's the trailer:




Yes, you're amazing. Thanks :)
